# Unable to access share by IP address Windows 10 1903

Tags: windows-10

I have two computers running Windows 10 Pro 1903 and have recently created a shared folder on one.

I initially tried to connect using the IP address and when trying to access the share it displays a message saying:

> "You do not have permission to access \\*ip*\*share*."

I then tried to connect using the system name and it successfully connected with no issues.

The system event viewer reports a successful login on both occasions.
Sharing is configured with password-protected sharing.

Although I got it working, I want to understand why it didn't work without the name. It seems like something has changed in windows networking, and so far my travels of the googlesphere has come back with nothing.

Is there something in Windows 10 network shares that prevents shares accessed directly via IP address?

Answer (score 0):

When you access the share using a *name* it is a *netbios name* its *netbios* name is more important than another name. A machine claims a *nebios name* and other machines confirm it.

if you use an IP address then you bypass this agreement between machines.

Think about it this way:
You live in a Cul-de-sac. you like your close neighbours.
anyone can get their house address.and their listed name.
a salesman goes to that place. knowing all the names and the house numbers.
but Mary and Bob had agreed, before hand. that if Bob recommends someone then he would use Marty. and Mary will use Julia.
if the salesman shows up at Bob's door saying "Hello Bob, Mary said you might be interested in this" if they say "Is Marty home? Julia has something that might interest him"

Comment: So if I bypass the agreement, why does it not work?